# What is the purpose of NetworkManager service in RHEL 6?

Tags: linux

Could anyone please explain the exact purpose of NetworkManager service in RHEL 6? Please also explain what happens if the service is stopped or started.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not programming related.

Comment: When is this homework assignment due?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkManager service is a replacement of network service. It provides some more advantage uses than network service, e.g. monitoring of network interfaces, automatic network detection and configuration, editing network scripts by many (also graphical) tools and more. If you stop this service, network configuration which is done by NetworkManager won't work and you have to configure netowrk in another way, e.g. with network service. If you then start NetworkManager again, your previous configuration will work fine again.